# Does anyone know of an anime movie about a robot that had a baby

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I don't remember much about the film but I do recall that it was about a female robot or cyborg that was married to a human man and some how was able to give birth to a child. I think her husband and child (it was a girl) were unaware of the fact that she was a robot, in fact I think her husband was a politician or something whose political party was against robot rights.

...Sorry if that information is terrible. I watched about half the movie years ago and I just recently remembered it. If you could help I would be SO grateful! I just spent an hour googling "movie about a robot that had a baby" :P

Comment: *"Sorry if that information is terrible."* As these things go this is pretty good. You hit the medium and style, a broad picture of the plot and several  key details. No complaints.

Answer (score 10):

I believe it's the second entry in the Armitage III series: [Armitage III: Dual Matrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303678/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). From the imdb description:

> Five years after the OAV series, Third series robot Naomi Armitage and
>   her husband Ross Sylibus now live peacefully on Mars with their
>   daughter, until a corporation wants to know the secrets of the third's
>   ability to bear children.

You may want to check out the [original OAV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366186/) as well (not the shortened movie version [Armitage III: Poly-Matrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109151)), as it's pretty good and gives you background on how Armitage got together with Ross and how she can actually get pregnant.

Comment: This was totally the movie I was thinking of after reading the title.  Great movies.